# Blocks are not being downloaded

Tags: mist, wallets, synchronization, blocks

After the attacks the clients are shit. At the moment, I am unable to download any blocks, except if I delete all the chaindata and it starts again.

I have less than 6k blocks left to download and I am stuck. It is the second time I've downloaded the entire chain...

Please help me with what to do. There are no detailed instructions anywhere, for noobs. ELI5 please. I've been trying everything apart from Parity. Tried all the other clients. Also, the 64bit Ethereum wallet is making my computer way too slow, to the point that it freezes many times...

I need to use the client tomorrow. I don't want to trust/rely on any web wallet.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What client are you using? How are you using it? (Mist? The Wallet? Native Geth? If Geth, what command line options are you passing it?) If you don't want to rely on web-based wallets, then there's a limit to how far ELI5 will get you...

Answer (score 4):

> I've been trying everything apart from Parity.

Start using parity. Here are some tweaks:

```
parity \                # run parity
  --mode passive \      # only wake up if there is anything to do
  --tracing off \       # disable full transaction tracing
  --pruning fast \      # pruning mode fast, maintain journal overlay
  --db-compaction hdd \ # use 'hdd' for slow hard drives or 'ssd' for solid state drives
  --cache-size 4096 \   # increase cache, should increase speed
  --fast-and-loose      # significant speedup (do not exit unclean in this mode)
```

Oneliner:

```
 parity --mode passive --tracing off --pruning fast --db-compaction hdd --cache-size 4096 --fast-and-loose
```

Comment: Add `--geth` in the command line options and Parity will simulate `geth` to provide the right connection information to Mist/Ethereum Wallet.

Comment: No need. Parity has Ethereum Wallet included on [127.0.0.1:8080](http://127.0.0.1:8080).

Answer (score 2):

ELYA5 answer: Just leave the wallet on. It will get past the point where it looks like it has frozen, and will very likely get up to speed in about a day or two.

Comment: Been running node for days and still stuck. So no, it won't "normalize" if you wait long enough.

Comment: If you have a standard hard disk, it will take a long time to process the spam accounts. It is much faster if you have a solid state drive. It will also help if you have more than 4Gb RAM + 4Gb swap, e.g. 8+8. I'm currently working out the number of empty accounts the attacker created and I've counted 15,683,880 so far, and my computations are not completed yet.