# Ethereum Wallet Will Not Sync

Tags: synchronization, ethereum-wallet-dapp, dao

This is a continuation of my first question re: DAO withdraw problems.

1. I'm running EW (latest update) on my MAC. I never connect with more than two peers and my wallet has not synced correctly since the DAO's inception. Assume others have had this problem. Here's a screenshot when I launch the EW App.

   [image: screenshot 0]
2. I understand the EW will not show correct balances until the entire block chain syncs. Does this also mean that I cannot execute the DAO Withdraw until the blockchain has 'completely' synced? I tried The DAO Withdraw a month ago without a complete blockchain sync. Nothing happened. Here's a screen shot of the transaction and none of the DAO was withdraw from the Main DAO.

   [image: screenshot 1]

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the latest version of the Ethereum Wallet? 0.8.7 at the time of speaking? If not [update](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases), if yes, [read this](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/9002/87).